# What does the author mean by "scaled version" of standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I was trying to understand how to use XYZ analysis when I came upon this [article](http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2016/10/15/abc-xyz-analysis-for-forecasting/). The author says that using coefficient of variation of an item (which is a ratio of standard deviation and average demand of the item) is flawed as it is a scaled version of standard deviation.

> Textbooks have supported the use of coefficient of variation. This is
>   so flawed that every time I read it… well, let me explain the issues.
>   **The coefficient of variation is a scaled version of the standard
>   deviation of the historical sales.** This tells us nothing about the
>   easiness to forecast sales or not.

^ extract from the article

I wanted to know -

1. What is meant by the statement in **bold** from the passage?
2. And, if you would entertain it, under what conditions scaled measures are flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They refer to [coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)

$$
c_v = \frac{\sigma}{\mu}
$$

so it calculates the [variability $\sigma$ *relatively* to the mean $\mu$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118497/how-to-interpret-the-coefficient-of-variation/118527#118527). But beware that there are problems with this statistic, as described in both links.