# How to compute Variability Independent of the Mean (VIM)

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, mean, standard-deviation

Although I find this reading regarding the interpretation of the [Coefficent of Variation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118497/) (CoV) very interesting, I did not found hints regarding the **Variability Independent of the Mean (VIM)** which is beeing largely employed in cardiovascular research. 
In particular, [VIM is calculated](https://doi.org/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.110.154708) by: $$VIM=(SD/mean^x)$$

> fitting a curve through a plot of SD systolic BP (SBP; y axis)
>   against mean SBP (x axis) with the parameter x estimated from the
>   curve

---

Moreover, I found other different definitions/approaches:

### [Computation 2:](https://doi.org/10.1161/HYPERTENSIONAHA.112.202143)

> VIM is calculated as the SD divided by the mean to the power `x` and
>   multiplied by the population mean to the power `x`. The power `x` is
>   obtained by fitting a curve through a plot of SD against mean using
>   the model `SD= a × mean x` , where `x` was derived by **nonlinear
>   regression analysis** as implemented in the `PROC NLIN` procedure of
>   the SAS package.

---

### [Computation 3:](https://doi.org/10.2337/dc18-1430)

> VIM is calculated as `100 * SD/mean^β`, where `β` is the regression
>   coefficient based on natural logarithm of SD on natural logarithm of
>   mean

---

### [Computation 4:](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0086514)

> VIM is a transformation of the standard deviation that is uncorrelated
>   with mean BP and is calculated as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> Where x is calculated from fitting a power model:
>
> [image]
>
> And [image]
>
> (i.e. the mean of all SBP readings across all patients to the power of
>   x).

---

Herein I propose a reproducible R example of computing SD and CoV. I would like to add the VIM too:

```
set.seed(101)
df <- data.frame( "ID" = paste("ID", seq(1,100,1), sep = ""),
                  "x1" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x2" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x3" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x4" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x5" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T))

# Compute row average
df$avg <- round(rowMeans(df[2:6]), 1)

# Compute row standard deviation
df$sntd <- round(matrixStats::rowSds(as.matrix(df[2:6])), 1)

# Compute coefficient of variation (CoV) as SD/mean * 100
df$CoV <- round(df$sntd/df$avg*100, 1)
```

To the best of my understanding, probably `nsl` [R function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/nls) can be used for non-linear regression. How?

Can anyone help with VIM computing using R and suggest/explain the above mentioned VIM definitions?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. Are you looking for a function/procedure to compute VIM in R?

Comment: Yes, do you know any package/function for computing VIM using R?

Comment: So, I've done some reading. What are you trying to use this for? This metric was developed to overcome increased variability that is correlated with increased mean when taking multiple measurements across a sample of individuals.I feel confident I could use `nls` to determine the p parameter in VIM, but the data you gave is not sufficient for doing this. Overall, it seems like a highly specialized case in which something like this might actually prove useful.

Comment: I've improved the example df. **VIM** is beeing largely used in top tier scientific articles and I would like to use VIM for cardiovascular research (i.e variation of systolic blood pressure - SBP) as already done. `x1` to `x5` indicates SBP measures.

Comment: I don't know about "top tier scientific articles". My conclusion if SD appears to be  a power of the mean is that the coefficient of variation is not a good idea in those circumstances. It is not that it is a good idea to seek some other summary collapsing SD and mean together differently. Without knowing how the power was estimated this is hard to interpret as (e.g.) least squares after logging both SD and mean and nonlinear least squares will typically give different estimates. Unless the power used is also reported clearly this is impossible to interpret.

Comment: The coefficient of variation is often oversold when the SD is not roughly proportional to mean. The solution for its being oversold is not another _ad hoc_ index. it is to describe and explain the pattern of variability, and possibly to work on a transformed scale.

Comment: @NickCox you're perfectly right. However, what I've to reply to a reviewer who is asking to add VIM in addition to SD, RMS and CoV on my analysis?

Comment: I would fight that vigorously.  FWIW, in work I never published a few decades ago I found the SD of annual rainfall scaling roughly as a power of the mean annual rainfall about 0.7. I still I hope to write it up, but not through proposing an alternative to the CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing your reproducible example, I have worked up what appears to be the idea behind VIM using `nls`.

```
library(matrixStats)

set.seed(101)

df <- data.frame( "ID" = paste("ID", seq(1,100,1), sep = ""),
                  "x1" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x2" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x3" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x4" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T),
                  "x5" = sample(90:220, size = 100, replace = T))

#compute row average
df$avg <- rowMeans(df[2:6])

#compute row standard deviation
df$sntd <- rowSds(as.matrix(df[2:6]))

#tune parameters for VIM
nls.vim = nls(sntd ~ k*avg^p, data=df, start=c(k=1,p=1))
summary(nls.vim)

#create scatterplot with overlay
plot(sntd ~ avg, data=df)
r = range(df$avg)
x.new = seq(r[1], r[2],length.out = 1000)
lines(x.new, predict(nls.vim,list(avg = x.new)), col='red', lty=2)
```

The output with parameters are:

```
Formula: sntd ~ k * avg^p

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
k 46.00223   59.06925   0.779    0.438
p -0.04593    0.25462  -0.180    0.857

Residual standard error: 10.2 on 98 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 9 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.367e-06
```

You can see this is almost flat, which makes sense given that the toy data is pretty uniform. This should be more interesting in data in which there is a positive correlation between mean and standard deviation.

Note: It may be necessary to change the initial parameters of the `nls` function to `start=c(k=1, p=0)` if the data scenario creates a singular gradient.

`p` in the `summary(nls.vim)` is the `x` in the above mentioned formula. For VIM you find the parameters by fitting across all row means and then can calculate specific VIMs by utilizing individual SDs and means. So if the VIM has parameters `k` and `p`, then the model is $$y=kx^p$$ and specific VIMs are $$VIM_i=k \cdot (s_i/\bar x_i)^p$$

Let's compute VIM for each row based of nls fit:

```
# VIM = k*(sntd/avg)^p
df$vim <- 46*(df$sntd/df$avg)^-0.04593
```

Comment: Although `nls` gives the error `number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50` I upvoted your answer. Another point is that VIM should be computed for each ID (row) as reported. Moreover, for what I understand, the `p` estimate should be the `x` in the formula stated n the question. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, my `p` is the `x` in your formula. For VIM you find the parameters by fitting across all row means and then can calculate specific VIMs by utilizing individual SDs and means. So if the VIM has parameters `k` and `p`, then the model is $y=kx^p$ and specific VIMs are VIM $i = k\cdot(s_i / \bar{x} _i)^p$. See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://n.neurology.org/highwire/filestream/132069/field_highwire_adjunct_files/1/Appendix_e-2.doc&ved=2ahUKEwia5_fz85LnAhXNVs0KHfdZB6kQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw3bRcuKacnrJ3sn1ya6u4Ki]

Comment: As for the iterations error, try adjusting the `k` and `p` parameters. Start with a good guess based on the scatterplot of mean vs SD.

Comment: I update your answer with some hints you provided here in the comments. Please revise it, so I will be happy to accept your final revision of the answer! thx

Comment: Made a slight change to the final formula and approved. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: A (much) better solution fits a line through a log-log plot.

Comment: Can anyone please explain to me why the entire ratio of (SD/mean) is raised to the power of p and not just the mean? As the other cited material clearly state VIM= k * SD / (mean^p) and NOT VIM = k * (SD/mean) ^ p. This is even the case in the document @Todd Burus linked for specific VIM scores. in a couple comments above . I am not very proficient in NLS so any help in this regard will be much appreciated.