Coefficient of Variation between two ratio metrics
I want to compare which metric is more stable (cost per impressions vs. cost per video view).
I have used CV (coefficient of variation) and looked for which metric CV is lower for the same campaign across multiple campaigns with different currencies. Is this an appropriate approach? Does it matter that data is not normally distributed?

It follows from principles discussed in e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118497/how-to-interpret-the-coefficient-of-variation that CV is a good measure to the extent that SD is proportional to the mean. This has nothing to do with whether distributions are normal (and indeed the fact that normal distributions can have zero or negative means is a problem for CVs at several levels. From the same thread, CV is often touted as a measure when the best way to think about data is on logarithmic scale. That could be true, or roughly so, for cost data.
